# html markup output doesnt load properly

Tags: php, html, wordpress, w3c-validation

Hi i have here a link in which i've sent to w3c validator and returns a validation error.
**& did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)**

```
<a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to&su=Home&body=http%3A%2F%2F50.16.158.199%2F&ui=2&tf=1&shva=1"></a>
```

i know that you have to replace the "&" into "&amp;" i already edited it inside the php file since im working on wordpress.

my problem is that why isn't the html markup get updated even though i've already edited it even the source code inside the php file shows the change i've made.

i want it to be like this when loaded as the markup.

```
<a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&amp;fs=1&amp;to&amp;su=Home&amp;body=http%3A%2F%2F50.16.158.199%2F&amp;ui=2&amp;tf=1&amp;shva=1"></a>
```

hope you can help me and give me an idea why it isn't loading.

Comment: Have you cleared cache folder?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek yes. im using the wp-super-cache to clear my cache. any ideas sir? i've been stuck on this problem for 3 days can't seem to find the answer to my problem.

Comment: i also deleted the cache manually inside the wp-content/cache/supercache. doesnt seem to make the changes